# python-docx one column have difference weight

Tags: python-3.x, python-docx

I want draw table like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYXfg.png)

I try this but it doesn't work:

```
table = doc.add_table(rows=2, cols=2)
table.style = 'Table Grid'
table.cell(0,0).width=Cm(3)
table.cell(0,1).width=Cm(12)
table.cell(1,0).width=Cm(7.5)
table.cell(1,1).width=Cm(7.5)
```

output:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9c29V.png)

Answer (score 0):

try with width property.

```
table = doc.add_table(rows=2, cols=2)
table.style = 'Table Grid'
table.cell(0,0).width=Cm(3)
table.cell(0,1).width=Cm(12)
table.cell(1,0).width=Cm(7.5)
table.cell(1,1).width=Cm(7.5)
```

Comment: sorry，my content have some mistake，i fixed it，thank you answer